# Why would exception catching be order-based instead of closest-inheritence based?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

In item 12 of More Effective C++, Meyers explains that while virtual calls are resolved according to dynamic type, using a best-fit algorithm, exception catching is based on order of catch clauses.

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};

void main()
{
try {throw B();}
catch(A &a) {}
catch{B &b} {} // never entered
}
```

*Is this the standard behavior now, 20 years later? What is the logic behind this difference from virtual functions?*

Comment: I would assume, that the order based catch-mechanism allows you to controll the order, while the other does not.

Comment: Actually gcc warns you about this behavior, probably is because the cost it has to throw and catch exceptions why they decided this approach.

Comment: @scones, this would be an answer, if you provided a use case where a well designed class structure needs to control the order of catching, instead of relying on the most derived type.

Comment: @Vorac What would be the desired behaviour with multiple inheritance? First mentioned, first served? First catched, first served? And if you want to use polymorphism, you can always catch by reference and call a virtual error handling method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is standard behavior. It is also standard in many popular programming languages like Java or C#.

This gives full control on exception handling to the code that catches the exception.

Consider exception hierarchy with multiple inheritance.